# Как правильно записать период времени в цифрах?

Tags: числительные, цифры, периоды-времени

Есть предложение:

> В 1970-90 годах он написал три монументальных книги, в которых изложил
>   свою концепцию постиндустриального общества.

Как записывать период времени цифрами? Условно говоря, "в восьмидесятых годах" - это ясно. А вот так писать можно? Или пишем только "в период с 1970 до 1990 года"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так писать можно, только необходимо наращение окончания к порядковым числительным, и желательно ставить тире без пробелов между цифрами.

*В 1970—90-х годах*

Answer (score 2):

Вот так:

[По поводу книги А. В. Гончаровой, Л. Н. Скаковской «У истока: фольклорные традиции в русской литературе 1970—90-х годов». Тверь, 2001. 240 с.](http://gramota.ru/biblio/magazines/mrs/28_480)

Тире без отбивок.

---

О [падежных наращениях](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/87-rubric-99):

> Если два порядковых числительных следуют через тире, то падежное
>   окончание наращивают:
>
> а) только у второго числительного, если падежное окончание у обоих
>   числительных одинаковое: 50–60-е годы, в 80–90-х годах;
>
> б) у каждого числительного, если падежные окончания разные: в 11-м –
>   20-х рядах.